# Help needed with picking JS/jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

What I have is a little jQuery based script intended to grayscale an image.

It works, but I have a big issue with picking the event that will trigger it.
I need it to simply be automatically triggered, once, when image is loaded. Now, this:

```
imgObj.ready
```

works perfectly in IE, in Firefox it's a gamble on each refresh, and in Safari/Chrome/Opera not at all.

This however:

```
imgObj.click
```

works great in all browsers, but I need it to happen automatically, without clicking.
(or with emulated click, but I didn't manage to make it, anyone knows how?)

And finally this:

```
imgObj.load
```

works "too good" - it works in all browsers, but keeps re-executing the function over and over - I tried putting a variable inside a function to make it be executed just once, but it didn't work, .load keeps re-executing.

Sorry for the long post, and thanks very much for reading through - below is the full code.

```
    var imgObj = $('#image'); 

        imgObj.click(function(){

            var imgObj = document.getElementById('image');

            if($.browser.msie){
                grayscaleImageIE(imgObj);
            } else {
                imgObj.src = grayscaleImage(imgObj);
            }           
        });

    function grayscaleImageIE(imgObj)
    {
        imgObj.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';
    }

    function grayscaleImage(imgObj)
    {


        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var imgW = imgObj.width;
        var imgH = imgObj.height;
        canvas.width = imgW;
        canvas.height = imgH;

        canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i
+ 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }

        canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();      
    }
```

Comment: Use $(document).ready(). Also look and see if there's a jQuery plugin that does this. It's clunky to mix jQuery and regular Javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
imgObj.one('load',function(){

        var imgObj = document.getElementById('image');

        if($.browser.msie){
            grayscaleImageIE(imgObj);
        } else {
            imgObj.src = grayscaleImage(imgObj);
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. About the other proposal $(document).ready - I've been trying it with no success, but this works great.

Comment: +1, You can simplify by just using `this` wherever `imgObj` is used as you are already handling that element..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var imgObj = $('#image'); 
    if($.browser.msie){
       grayscaleImageIE(imgObj);
    } else {
       imgObj.src = grayscaleImage(imgObj);
    }     
});
```